# Displaying a table view as a pop up

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview, popup

I have a table view and some images in it .I have certain images in my table view which have same name as some other images.Now what i want is that when i click on an image then with that click a pop up window will be shown on screen consisting of a table view which will show the all images with the same name.So basically my question is how to display a table view in pop up window.Do i have to write any other class for that .Please help.I am a fresher in this case.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UIPopoverController to display your TableView.

Comment: UIPopoverController *popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tableResultViewController];

You have to then dismiss the popOverViewController in the delegate messages

Comment: how to dismiss popOverViewController in dlegate method

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UIPopOverViewController, and it will simply extend the Table View methods, the same way you would do it in any other view controller.

Comment: provide me a demo or samplec ode please ,as i havent done it yet

Comment: Here's a demo: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial

Now what you would do is in the UIPopOver .h file, just add  <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> after @interface PopOverViewController to allow it to implement table view methods. Or you can just change the whole class to a UITableView instead of UIViewController from interface builder.